# GWT Fileupload, what event or handler when user click the choose file button

Tags: google-app-engine, events, gwt, file-upload, handler

I am new to GWT/GAE.
To use GAE Blobstore service, a upload url must be returned from server side, as the tutorial in [this blog](http://www.fishbonecloud.com/2010/12/tutorial-gwt-application-for-storing.html) .

But it seems this get upload url service can be called while user is browsing file, thus I need to find the event to handle when user press the choose file button, and set the formpanel's action attribute there.

fileupload itself has attach/detach or change event, but it seems not what i am looking for.

My code which can do upload to blobstore is as follow:
The upload form is:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gwt.cell.client.DateCell;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FileUpload;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormPanel.SubmitCompleteEvent;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlowPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextArea;

public class UploadFilePanel implements EntryPoint {
    private FileServiceAsync upls = GWT.create(FileService.class);
    AsyncCallback<String> callback;
    FormPanel form;
    String upload_url;

public void onModuleLoad() {

    get_upload_url();

    RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();

    FlowPanel flowPanel = new FlowPanel();
    rootPanel.add(flowPanel, 0, 0);

    add_submit_form(flowPanel);
}

private void add_submit_form(FlowPanel flowPanel) {
    VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
    flowPanel.add(panel);

    // Create a FormPanel and point it at a service.
    form = new FormPanel();
    panel.add(form);
    form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
    form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);

    form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new SubmitCompleteHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
            RootPanel.get().clear();
            RootPanel.get().getElement()
                    .setInnerHTML("upload complete " + event.toString());
        }
    });

    form.setSize("222px", "52px");

    // Create a FileUpload widget.
    FileUpload upload = new FileUpload();
    form.setWidget(upload);
    upload.setSize("100%", "100%");
    upload.setName("myFile");

    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    panel.add(textArea);
    textArea.setWidth("100%");

    // Add a 'submit' button.
    Button submitbtn = new Button("Submit");
    panel.add(submitbtn);
    submitbtn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            upls.get_upload_url("/stmtgen/upload", callback);
        }
    });
}

private void get_upload_url() {
    callback = new AsyncCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            form.setAction(result);
            upload_url = result;
            form.submit();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            RootPanel.get().clear();
            RootPanel.get().getElement()
                    .setInnerHTML("Can't get upload url");
        }
    };
    if (upls == null)
        upls = GWT.create(FileService.class);
}
}
```

The Async service I used to get upload url is this:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
public interface FileServiceAsync {
void get_upload_url(String up, AsyncCallback<String> callback);
}
```

The problem is when user hit submit button, there is two services invocation which slow down the response.

I tried addHandler(Handler, Type) as below, it doesn't work.

```
FileUpload upload = new FileUpload();
upload.addHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    //get upload url here
                }
            }, ClickEvent.getType()
);
```

Comment: Instead of pointing to the 2010 blog please attach relevant code snippets using latest libs and rephrase your question with example.

Comment: I add code, which is using the latest GWT and GAE libs, Google Eclipse plugin, and they can do upload file, and get upload url.